# Why might visual studio 2013 not allow me to create new C++ CLR class libraries?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

For some reason, when I try and create a new C++ CLR class library or console application (deosn't seem to matter which version of .net I target either) in visual studio 2013 the GUI stalls saying `'Creating project XXX.vcxproj'...`.

I've tried repairing VS2013 and I've tried completely uninstalling and re-installing but nothing helps.

C# projects create without any problems.

What might cause this?

Comment: Almost always caused by a wonky add-in.  Use a debugger if you have no idea what might cause the deadlock.  You have one, start VS again and use Tools + Attach to Process.

Comment: I just gave that a shot Hans but the only thread which mentioned a plug-in was one for application insights. Uninstalling that made no difference.

Comment: Uninstalling GhostDoc (which I'd forgotten I even installed) solved it. Thanks Hans!

Comment: If you post your suggestion as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It is not the kind of answer I want to support, they shoot messengers around here.  Feel free to post your own answer or delete your question if you don't want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst this is a relatively broad subject, I'm leaving this Q&A up here in case anyone else has a similar issue and the suggestions of things you can check could help someone else. The answer to my particular problem here was that a plug-in I had installed (GhostDoc) was at fault. Uninstalling and re-installing that plugin solved my issue.

If you have similar problems, try uninstalling all your plugins first. It's worth mentioning that plugins aren't necessarily uninstalled when Visual Studio is removed / re-installed (or at least Ghost Doc isn't) so simply re-installing Visual Studio won't necessarily solve the problem.

Hans' comments on using a debugger to check what plugins are loaded and that plugins are likely to be the cause are worth a shot too.